# Найти суму чисел которые входят в диапазон между двумя числами

Tags: c++

Как найти суму чисел которые входят в диапазон между двумя числами?
Суть задания: пользователь вводит два числа, затем программа находит между этими двумя числами, только те числа, которые имеют разные цифры. Нужно вывести сумму этих чисел которые входят у промежуток(вывод промежутка с числами есть у коде).

Фрагмент кода в который нужно это добавить:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, m, k = 0, p = 0, flag, i = 0, j, dig[10];
    do
    {
        printf("Enter m and n (m < n):\n");
        scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
        if (m < n)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
            printf("\Error- m > n! Try again.\n\n");
    } while (k == 0);

    //printf("The sum of numbers in the interval [%d, %d] are:\n" );
    printf("Numbers in the interval [%d, %d] are:\n", m++, n--);
    for (k = m; k <= n; k++)
    {
        p = k;
        flag = 0;
        dig[i] = 0;
        i = 0;
        if (p < 10)
        { 
            continue;
        }   
        while (p > 0)
        { 
            dig[i] = p % 10;
            p = p / 10;
            i++;
        }
        dig[i] = -1;
        for (i = 0; dig[i] > -1; i++)
        { 
            for (j = i + 1; dig[j] > -1; j++)
            { 
                if (dig[i] == dig[j])
                { 
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        if (flag == 0)
        {
            printf("%d\t", k);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Чисел? Или цифр этих чисел? Вы явно решаете какую-то не ту задачу. Изложите задание точно, полно и недвусмысленно, pls. А вообще сумма чисел в диапазоне [m,n] равна (m+n)\*(n+1-m)/2

Comment: в тот промежуток, что в коде, входят только числа с разными цифрами, нужна просто сума этих всех чисел у промежутке.

Comment: 1. Изложите **точное** задание в вопросе, и 2. приведите заголовок вопроса в соответствие вопросу. На всякий случай - ц*И*фра пишется через "и".

Comment: Хорошо, я исправил.

Comment: Число 223 имеет разные цифры? А 11223?

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool dif(int k) {
    int dig[10] = {0};

    while (k) {
        dig[k % 10]++;
        k /= 10;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        if (dig[i] > 1) return false;

    return true;
    }

int main() {
    int m, n, sum = 0;
    cin >> m >> n;

    for (int k = m; k <= n; k++) {
        if (dif(k)) sum += k;
        }

    cout << sum;
    }
```

Comment: спасибо конечно, но этот фрагмент кода не правильно считает.

Comment: Может, у вас просто не должны входить сами числа m и n?

Comment: @Alexander333 думаю, было бы правильно  привести варианты входных данных и "правильных ответов".